# conversion on pandas queries python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a .dat file and to extract lines which their timestamp==2000 and to save them on a file, here is my code and I get that error on converting query [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Tnr.png)

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

make sure your field is a datetime

```
ratings_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ratings_df['timestamp'])
```

You can then pull year from it

```
ratings_df['timestamp'].dt.year
```

Comment: it return the year 1970, my file does not contain that year

Comment: you don't give an example of what a timestamp value looks like

Comment: here is an example : 956715569

Comment: yeah that would have helped to know that field was in seconds

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer `def dateparse (time_in_secs):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
ratings_df = pd.read_table('~/ml-1m/ratings.dat', header=None, sep='::', names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'],parse_dates=['timestamp'],date_parser=dateparse)` 
thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You should use the pandas function [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead of the native datetime functionality.

```
ratings_df.loc[pd.to_datetime(ratings_df['Timestamp'], unit='s').year == 2000, colonnes]
```

The format of the timestamp is an important factor to get the right output.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18112351)

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I will edit my answer :)